# How do I add comas between the numbers and [] at the beginning and end in python(for list)

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have this code but I want to add [] at the beginning and end as well as commas between the numbers and make them all on 1 line (it is a code that looks for all even numbers in a list)

```
list=[33,5,12,6,17,11,20]
for number in list :
    if (number % 2) == 0:
         print(number)
```

answer it gives me:

```
 12
 6
 22
```

answer I want :

```
[12,6,22]
```

Comment: btw don't use `list` as a variable name. It is a built-in.

Comment: @quamrana yes i know but it did not let me post it if i did not fix the typing error i wrote it as liste initialy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you just asked for is basically a list. So all you have to do is append the values into a list:

```
inputlist=[33,5,12,6,17,11,20]
outputlist = []
for number in inputlist :
    if (number % 2) == 0:
        outputlist.append(number)
print(outputlist)
```

Output will be `[12,6,20]`

Comment: thx bro it worked i wil check you in a few minutes when it lets me

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a list comprehension:

```py
numbers = [33,5,12,6,17,11,20]
evens = [number for number in numbers if (number % 2) == 0]
print(evens)
```

Comment: What about mine?

Comment: @MatheoGermanos: of course you can. Its standard practice in python.

Comment: @quamrana i know it is but unfortunitly i cant use it

Comment: What, do you get an allergic reaction or something?

Comment: @quamrana no its just that my teacher told me not to use it in class

Comment: Well, they had better have a good reason, otherwise I'll be having words.

Comment: @quamrana well its prob cuzz it has not been shown in class yet and i cant use what we have not done

Comment: Well, at least this will prompt a discussion about whether the two pieces of code are equivalent or not.

Comment: yeh i will ask in my next class

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution,

```
def even(n):
    return n%2 == 0

my_list = [33, 5, 12, 6, 17, 11, 20]
print(filter(even, my_list))
```

there are other ways...